# How to create an angular validation message directive

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

I am new to angular and maybe trying to do the wrong thing.

What I am trying to, is to create a validation message directive, which can show validation message for a specific input field in a form. It should only show the validation message for required fields in case the input field is missing a value.

I've tried with the following HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="myApp">

  <head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.0.7/angular.min.js"></script>
    <script src="script.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body>    
    <form name="myForm">
  <input name="myInput" type="text" x-ng-model="object.input" required/><br/> 
  <span ng-show="myForm.myInput.$error.required" >Value required (working)</span><br/>
     <span x-msg-required="myForm.myInput"></span>
    </form>
  </body>
</html>
```

and the JS:

```
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
app.directive('msgRequired', function() {
  return {
    link : function(scope, element, attrs) {
      element.text('Value required');
      attrs.$set('ngShow', attrs.msgRequired + '.$error.required' );
    }
  };
```

});

The first span element with out directive shows the validation message as expected. The span element with my directive seems to always show the validation message. I am for sure not understanding the directives in angular. What am I missing or is there better ways of streamlining validation messages in angular?

There is a plunker: http://plnkr.co/edit/Gjvol8inw1DlWjHomZQw

Comment: In case you haven't seen them, there's an excellent tutorial on angularjs form validation here: http://blog.brunoscopelliti.com/form-validation-the-angularjs-way and one on custom form validation directives here: http://shazwazza.com/post/Reference-the-current-form-controller-in-AngularJS  Hope that helps.

Answer (score 4):

I was also bothered by this with Angular and created a directive suite in AngularAgility called Form Extension to fix this very issue. It automatically generates validation messages for you based on whats on your element. It is also very configurable and even will generate labels for you if you'd like.

Consider normally having to type something like this to get validation:

```
<div ng-form="exampleForm">
    <label for="firstName">First Name *</label>
    <div>
        <input type="text" id="firstName" name="firstName" ng-model="person.firstName"
               ng-minlength="2" />
        <div ng-show="exampleForm.firstName.$dirty && exampleForm.firstName.$error.minlength">
            First Name must be at least 2 characters long.
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

That's a pain. With the plugin you can do something like this instead:

```
<div ng-form="exampleForm">
    <div>
        <input type="text" aa-auto-field="person.firstName" ng-minlength="2" />
    </div>
</div>
```

Here are some relevant links:

[Extensive demo](http://angularagility.herokuapp.com/#/home)

[Blog post explaining it](http://johnculviner.com/introducing-angularagility-formextensions/)

[Source on GitHub](https://github.com/AngularAgility/AngularAgility)

Answer (score 0):

So I see this is a couple months old, but in case anyone is looking for something that works:

I updated your Javascript to this:

```
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);

app.directive('msgRequired', function($compile) {
    return {
      //transclude: true,
      restrict: "A",
        link: function(scope, element, attrs) {
            element[0].innerHTML = 'Value required in angular directive';
            attrs.$set('ngShow', attrs.msgRequired + ".$error.required");

            $compile(element)(scope)
        }
    };
  });
```

which seems to work.  I am however doing something VERY similar in another project, and getting an infinite compile loop :( Investigating that...

plnkr lives [here](http://plnkr.co/edit/DgOZCPyGgXsjaojY0Lpi).